# Prove every finite group can be embedded into $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've read the proof on wikipedia, but I honestly don't understand it.  Could someone explain?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The idea is simply that the action of a finite group $X$ on itself gives a map $X \to S_{|X|}$ that's clearly injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is prety intuitive, all you have to do is think about the way group elements act on the rest of the group. If your group can be put in order as (say) the list $\{g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5\}$, look at the way left multiplication by $g_1$ works on the group: it takes it to the set $\{g_1^2 $ $,g_1g_2$  $,g_1g_3$ $,g_1g_4$ 
$,g_1g_5\}$. This has the same number of elements as the original group, and it's made up of distinct elements, so it's the same list as the original, in a different order! Every element works this way by left (or right) multiplicaiton: it reorders --or permutes -- the group. Therefore every element acts as a permutation by left multiplication. This isn't really a rigorous proof, but does it help the concept make any more sense?